# Sent Items folder mails are not syncing properly

Tags: email, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I have issue with sent items folder I am unable to sync mails properly. Except that all are working fine. Can you please assist.

```
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection1 = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or);
SearchFilter searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.From, email.trim());
SearchFilter searchFilter2 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.DisplayTo,email.trim());
SearchFilter searchFilter3 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.DisplayCc,email.trim());
searchFilterCollection1.add(searchFilter1);
searchFilterCollection1.add(searchFilter2);
searchFilterCollection1.add(searchFilter3);
FindItemsResults findResults = service.findItems(folder.getId(),earchFilterCollection1, view);
```

Above code is working fine for all folders except sent item folder. It's not fetching properly items in the exchange. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchFilter searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.From, email.trim());
```

This is redundant in the SentItems folders as this folder will only contain a copy of Messages that where sent from that Mailbox. I would suggest you drop that and retry.

Comment: I didn't get you what I need to drop ??. Do you mean that request.

Comment: Dont use the above SearchFilter on the SentItems folder as its redundant eg all the messages in that folder are going to be from that Mailbox.